# Obtain server supported cipher suites sent during the handshake protocol in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm trying to obtain the supported cipher suite sent by the server during the the handshake protocol in an iOS app for **HTTPS** connections. So that, I could validate it against the recommended cipher suite in NIST Special Publication 800-52: Guidelines for the Selection, Configuration, and Use of Transport Layer Security (TLS) Implementations Table 3-2.

I tried looking into the class *NSURLProtectionSpace*'s methods and other related entities like *SecTrust*, *SecCertificate* functions, and ran out of luck. I was unable to find anything in Apple doc titled as "Certificate, Key, and Trust Services Reference" too.

I found something interesting though. A 'C' function *SSLGetSupportedCiphers*. This needs a *SSLSessionRef* object as parameter. And then I wasn't able obtain *SSLSessionRef* object from *NSProtectionSpace* object as this is the only parameter provide by the delegate

```
"connection:willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:".
```

And of course how should I be able to, as session is not yet established. (But I'm guessing that this class might have information about supported cipher suites as it represent the server realm).

Question: How to get cipher suite supported by the server, sent during the handshake protocol at client end, before sending credential to server.

Note: I can only use standard Apple API. OpenSSL is not available as option. :-(